# Vertical slide-down animation not working on iOS

Tags: android, html, ios, css, animation

I wrote the following code:

```
.sp #sec01::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(100vh - 120px);
    right: 50%;
    border-left:solid 1px #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #fff;
    content: "";
    -webkit-animation-name: spslide;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-name: spslide;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    max-height:50px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spslide {
    0% {height: 1px}
    100% {height: 50px}
}

@-moz-keyframes spslide {
    0% {height: 1px}
    100% {height: 50px}
}

@-o-keyframes spslide {
    0% {height: 1px}
    100% {height: 50px}
}

@keyframes spslide {
    0% {height: 1px}
    100% {height: 50px}
}
```

You can view my website [here](https://stg-forest.toppan.co.jp/).

- username: `forest`
- password: `testweb`

I have tested the website on android where the animation is working as intended but the line is not being animated on iOS (iPhone).

I am referring to this [vertical line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0UWW.jpg).